# Get data value from Fragment into Main activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, server, badge

I am trying to create a notification badge like Whatsapp (Near tabs) but unable to fetch data value which are stored in a fragment but as the badge would be in the main activity, I'm unable to get(call) the dynamic value from the fragment.

Below are the codes:

> LoadJSON Code

```
private void loadJSONClaim() {
    sp = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String usr = sp.getString(UserID, "");
    Retrofit retrofitclaim = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://ec2-54-191-118-200.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RequestInterfaceClaim requestclaim = retrofitclaim.create(RequestInterfaceClaim.class);
    Call<JSONResponseClaim> call = requestclaim.getJSONClaim(usr);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponseClaim>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponseClaim> call, Response<JSONResponseClaim> responseclaim) {

            JSONResponseClaim jsonResponseClaim = responseclaim.body();
            dataclaim = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponseClaim.getAndroidClaim()));
            adapterclaim = new DataAdapterClaim(dataclaim);
            mRecyclerViewClaim.setAdapter(adapterclaim);
            eligitem.setText("    Eligible to earn   " + dataclaim.size() + " items");
          /* if(dataclaim.size()==0){
                filldata.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                emptyclaim.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                emptyclaim.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                filldata.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }*/
        }
```

So either the below code works in Fragment or data values get called in Main activity shouldresolve the issue, I guess.

> MainActivity.java

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CleverTapAPI ct;

    BadgeView badgeView = new BadgeView(this,tabLayout);
    badgeView.setText("2");
    badgeView.show();
```

Can anybody help on this?

EDIT: refined question

Comment: Usually i just make a reference to my fragment from my activity. Then i make a public method on my fragment to get the data value from my activity. As simple as that

Comment: if you want to call mainActivity method whenever you like from fragment create listener in fragment and add callbacks in main activity

Comment: @HendraWijayaDjiono, can we get a dynamic value using the same?

Comment: I'd agree with bryan c, best practice would be to have a listener in your fragment that your activity implements for callbacks.

Comment: @bryanc hey I'm still a beginner with Android, can you give me an example? I'm trying to get the dynamic data from a fragment (which is coming from a server).

Comment: just a minute ,i can show you how use this way for your question

Comment: The documentation tells you how to send data from a Fragment to an Activity (and optionally to another Fragment). http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: @Sandeep Singh i added my answer but if you have any question please create a chat and tell me

Comment: Oh sorry, maybe i don't understand your problem correctly from my comment before. Yes, you can use a listener pattern. So your Activity will implement that listener, and you can call the method on the listener from your Fragment, like this: ((YourListenerThatImplementedByActivity)getActivity()).aMethodToDoSomething();

Answer (score 2):

first create an interface with whatever you like to send where ever:

```
public Interface IEventListener{
   public void somMethod(data_type_toSend data)
}
```

then in your fragment's class define and in constructor initiate this interface:

```
IEventListener myListener;
public YourFragment (IEventListener listener){
     myListener=listener
}
```

finally let your activity implement your interface

```
public class myActivity extends ... implements **IEventListener**{
```

then in your activity override event callbacks :

```
 @Override
  public void somMethod(data_type_toSend data){
//what you want to do with sent data to activity
}
```

Comment: Just a helpful tip, if your in android studio and you generate a 'generic' activity with fragments, it will give you a solid example of this pattern as well.